# Visual Studio 2015 project template type

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility, project-template

I'm creating a project template and suffering placing it into a particular section in "New Project" window. I found a *MyTemplate.vstemplate* xml-like file inside the template folder and there is an entry 'ProjectType'. And that seems to be the right way to solve the problem just setting a proper value there, but I can't find all the list of available types. No problem placing the template into 'Visual C#' or 'Visual Basic' sections, but I would like to put in under 'Other Project Types' or 'Visual Studio Solutions'.

And the greatest achievement would be to setup the template along with an extension.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

**csproj content:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ModuleRegistry.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <Target Name="TemplateProjectOutputGroup">
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ProjectType` that you should use for that.

Edit the csproj that contains the MyTemplate.vstemplate file and set the `OutputSubPath` value like this:

```
<VSTemplate Include="MyTemplate.vstemplate">
    <OutputSubPath>ELEVATION</OutputSubPath>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: But there is no such entry as `VSTemplate`

Comment: You need to add it.

Comment: Then, where exactly? Under `<project>` or deeper? And what value do I have to use to get in 'Visual Studio Solutions' section?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. You don't have MyTemplate.vstemplate listed in your csproj file? If you do how is it listed?

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. But `vstemplate` is not listed in the project file anywhere and you're proposing to add it. And I'm asking where exactly it should be added.

Comment: Could you please put the csproj content as it is now? In the part that lists the MyTemplate.vstemplate file?

Comment: Put it inside a <ItemGroup><ItemGroup>.